How to convert octal in ascii characters by using substitute() in Vim9?
My attempt:
vim9script

var text = 'Hello \\123world\\045!'
echom text->substitute('\\\o\o\o', => printf("%c", str2nr(submatch(0), 8)), 'g')

result in E15 and E116.

I would do the following:
vim9script

var text = "Hello \\123world\\045!"
echom substitute(text, '\\\(\o\o\o\)', (m) => nr2char(str2nr(m[1], 8)), 'g')

The substitute call is made using a lambda function: (m) => str2nr(m[1], 8) where m is the array of match m[i] corresponds to submatch(i).
More information with :help substitute()

Thanks! Perhaps there is a nr2char missing? Also, some explanation about that m and m[1] would be appreciated!

Thanks for the feedback :-) I have given more information about the lambda function used in the expression. The nr2char is not needed Vim does that for you ;-)

Thanks! But I just noticed that 123 octal is equivalent to S in ascii...  But that is not the value returned.

I didn't understood the purpose (my bad). I have corrected the solution accordingly :-)

With previous vimscript, the pattern is wrong, you would have needed to ignore the backslashes. I guess this is the same in vimscript 2.
echo text ->substitute('\\\\\(\o\o\o\)', '\=nr2char(str2nr(submatch(1), 8))', "g")

